# Laravel 5.4, Auth0 - Class 'Auth0\Login\Facade\Auth0' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, auth0

I am trying to implement Auth0, and so far I made the login. But I am having issues with trying to get user data;

This are my routes:

```
Route::get('/auth0/callback', '\Auth0\Login\Auth0Controller@callback');

Route::get('/', function () {
    dd(Auth0::getUser());
});

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return \App::make('auth0')->login();
});
```

The **dd(Auth0::getUser());** is trowing following error:

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Class 'Auth0\Login\Facade\Auth0' not found
```

The **aliases**:

```
'Auth0' => Auth0\Login\Facade\Auth0::class
```

**AppServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Auth0\Login\Contract\Auth0UserRepository as Auth0UserRepositoryContract;
use Auth0\Login\Repository\Auth0UserRepository as Auth0UserRepository;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            Auth0UserRepositoryContract::class,
            Auth0UserRepository::class );
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try to run : `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run composer `dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:clear` to make sure the class can be found.

for `Auth0` you can still find auth user information with :

```
Auth::user();
```

or simply with helpers functions  like:

```
auth()->user()
```

if you read Auth0 documentation :

> Now, after user has logged in, you will be able to access to the
>   logged user info with Auth::user().

please follow this tutorial : https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel/01-login

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't import the specified class `Auth0\Login\Facade\Auth0`, you can use backslash.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    dd(\Auth0::getUser());
});
```

Comment: not needed because he's calling it from the route file, not from the controller, this is the same thing for the `Route::` part